# Optimizing a MySql database for large queries

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization, performance-testing

I am building a big database that. one of my tables have 300K records and another once has 5 million record.
I currently have all foreign keys and the column named "ph.trigger_on" indexed.

My question is how can I optimize my table/query to get a faster results? I tried to create a view with this code then from this view I can get all the information that I need when I do a query to this view.

By the query is still slow and I am having difficulties understanding the results that EXPLAIN is showing.
This is my current query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
ac.account_name AS accountName,
tm.name AS teamName,
cp.name AS campaignName,
cc.call_code_name AS callCode,
rc.result_code_name AS resultCode,
zn.name AS zoneName,
ind.name AS industry,
(su.first_name + su.middle_name + su.last_name) AS owner_name,
su.login_user AS ownerLoginUser,
(su1.first_name + su1.middle_name + su1.last_name) AS firstAttemptBy,
(su2.first_name + su2.middle_name + su2.last_name) AS lastAttemptBy,
(su3.first_name + su3.middle_name + su.last_name) AS modifiedBy,
ci.name AS clientName,
ph.trigger_on AS triggerOn,
ph.created_on AS createdOn,
ph.first_attempt_on AS firstAttemptOn,
ph.call_subject AS callSubject,
ph.status,
ph.last_attempt_on AS lastAttemptOn,
ph.total_attempts AS totalAttempts,
ph.call_direction AS callDirection,
ph.call_notes AS callNotes,
ph.call_duration AS callDuration,
ph.modified_on AS modifiedOn

FROM phone_calls AS ph
INNER JOIN accounts AS ac ON ph.account_id = ac.account_id
INNER JOIN clients AS ci ON ac.client_id = ci.client_id
INNER JOIN industries AS ind ON ac.industry_id = ind.industry_id
INNER JOIN call_codes AS cc ON ph.call_code_id = cc.call_code_id
INNER JOIN time_zones AS zn ON ph.time_zone_id = zn.time_zone_id
INNER JOIN users AS su ON ph.owner_id = su.user_id

LEFT  JOIN teams AS tm ON ph.team_id = tm.team_id
LEFT  JOIN result_codes AS rc ON ph.result_code_id = rc.result_code_id
LEFT  JOIN campaigns AS cp ON ph.campaign_id = cp.campaign_id
LEFT  JOIN users AS su1 ON ph.first_attempt_by = su1.user_id
LEFT  JOIN users AS su2 ON ph.last_attempt_by = su2.user_id
LEFT  JOIN users AS su3 ON ph.modified_by = su3.user_id
WHERE ph.trigger_on < now()
LIMIT 1000
```

this is my current output.

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  ci  ALL PRIMARY             1   
1   SIMPLE  zn  ALL PRIMARY             1   Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1   SIMPLE  su  ALL PRIMARY             1   Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1   SIMPLE  ac  ref PRIMARY,client_id,industry_id   client_id   4   rdi_cms.ci.client_id    95917   
1   SIMPLE  ind eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   rdi_cms.ac.industry_id  1   
1   SIMPLE  ph  ref owner_id,call_code_id,account_id,time_zone_id,trigger_on    account_id  4   rdi_cms.ac.account_id   11  Using where
1   SIMPLE  tm  ALL PRIMARY             1   Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1   SIMPLE  rc  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   rdi_cms.ph.result_code_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  cc  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   rdi_cms.ph.call_code_id 1   
1   SIMPLE  cp  ALL PRIMARY             1   Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1   SIMPLE  su1 ALL PRIMARY             1   Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1   SIMPLE  su2 ALL PRIMARY             1   Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1   SIMPLE  su3 ALL PRIMARY             1   Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

What can I do to improve my tables or my query.

Comment: The most important thing is make sure all condition-fields are indexed: all JOIN ON fields and all WHERE fields. I don't think thers's much else you can do when joining 13 (!!) tables... Do you really need 12 joins? If some part is just to limit the results, you might try that in a separate query. **Sometimes** it's faster (query cache!) if you create several smaller queries.

Comment: A view is not supposed to speed anything up! You could try to reduce the complexity by reducing the number of joins. You also may try to split this query into multiple subsequent queries in your language of choice. you also could try to move some joins into subquerys. If the optimizer manages to execute these subqueries after the crossproduct than you would win some time too.

Comment: I know views are not an going to speed up anything but it will make writing the script much easier instead of doing 5 joins every time i can just call the view. But what I am getting from the response it to avoid creating a big view but create a large query every time in my PHP script so this way I can also join the needed information.

Comment: You have a lot of ALL's in the explain result. [That means a full table scan.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html#jointype_all) Not sure what ALL PRIMARY means.

Answer (score 2):

it could make a difference if you push a join into a subquery in the SELECT part of your query like this:

```
SELECT
ac.account_name AS accountName,
tm.name AS teamName,
cp.name AS campaignName,
cc.call_code_name AS callCode,
rc.result_code_name AS resultCode,
(SELECT zn.name FROM time_zones AS zn WHERE ph.time_zone_id = zn.time_zone_id) AS zoneName,
(SELECT ind.name FROM industries AS ind WHERE ac.industry_id = ind.industry_id) AS industry,
(SELECT su.first_name + su.middle_name + su.last_name users AS su WHERE ph.owner_id = su.user_id) AS owner_name,
su.login_user AS ownerLoginUser,
(su1.first_name + su1.middle_name + su1.last_name) AS firstAttemptBy,
(su2.first_name + su2.middle_name + su2.last_name) AS lastAttemptBy,
(su3.first_name + su3.middle_name + su.last_name) AS modifiedBy,
ci.name AS clientName,
ph.trigger_on AS triggerOn,
ph.created_on AS createdOn,
ph.first_attempt_on AS firstAttemptOn,
ph.call_subject AS callSubject,
ph.status,
ph.last_attempt_on AS lastAttemptOn,
ph.total_attempts AS totalAttempts,
ph.call_direction AS callDirection,
ph.call_notes AS callNotes,
ph.call_duration AS callDuration,
ph.modified_on AS modifiedOn

FROM phone_calls AS ph
INNER JOIN accounts AS ac ON ph.account_id = ac.account_id
INNER JOIN clients AS ci ON ac.client_id = ci.client_id
INNER JOIN call_codes AS cc ON ph.call_code_id = cc.call_code_id
INNER JOIN time_zones AS zn ON ph.time_zone_id = zn.time_zone_id

LEFT  JOIN teams AS tm ON ph.team_id = tm.team_id
LEFT  JOIN result_codes AS rc ON ph.result_code_id = rc.result_code_id
LEFT  JOIN campaigns AS cp ON ph.campaign_id = cp.campaign_id
LEFT  JOIN users AS su1 ON ph.first_attempt_by = su1.user_id
LEFT  JOIN users AS su2 ON ph.last_attempt_by = su2.user_id
LEFT  JOIN users AS su3 ON ph.modified_by = su3.user_id
WHERE ph.trigger_on < now()
LIMIT 1000
```

here i pushed 3 joins into your SELECT part.

Comment: I don't see what you have done to my query other that removing 2 joins that I would need.

Comment: i did not REMOVE them! i just moved them to a later state of execution

Comment: The joins are now only done for rows that actually matched. First the filter, then the select. Smart.

Comment: I see what you have done now. So doing subquery is faster that doing inner join?

Comment: it might be! it doesn't have to. pretty much depends on the optimizer. just try it.